# Should plists be imported to CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have several big plists in my app. I use them to get necessary input data to my app. While app is running, this data used in various random visual representations. Also, I have favorites feature, where I save some favorite pieces of data. For favorites feature I use CoreData. I transfer some object from my "runtime" data to CoreData and save it.
But should I transfer all data from plists to CoreData, when I launch app for the first time? Or is it ok, to use plists to get data from them every launch?

For example, if we'd talking about reading app. We have some text file on disk. Should I transfer all file to CoreData, when launch first time? Or is it ok, just to save user bookmarks to CoreData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Core data` and `plist` both are used for store the data. so, if you get data from `plis`t or `core data` at every launch, there is no problem at all. But if you want to manage complex relational database then you should use core data or sqlite. so, choose storing system as per your requirement like if you want to store user's default credential then you can use `nsuserdefault` and if you use it to store complex data then also it will work fine but you will possible to face trouble to face some kind of functional operation. So, main concern and your answer there is no difference you get in performance whatever database system you used.

Hoe this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to only read the data or update all data from plist allmost all the time `plist` may be ok, also it will be more easy to access then Core Data

Both plist and Core data can be used as persistant storage, but Core Data will have some addtional benifit like i have listed below:

- Data stored in the Core Data is pretty secure, so if you can store some sesitive information in the Core Data, data store in plist can be seen directly in some ways.
- If you have to perform some insert,update,delete or search on the data it will be better on the Core Data instead of plist.
- If you want something like relation or mapping between data it will be possible with Core Data only

So based on the requirement you can choose your storage options